# extract first 5 and last 5 characters from a string using php?

Tags: php, md5

I have an MD5 alpha-numeric. How can I get the first five characters and last five characters, and put them in one string using `PHP`?

For example: "**aabbc**cddeef**fgghh**" will become "aabbcfgghh".

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First of all - accept your recent answers.

You can do this with [`substr`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) function:

```
$input  = 'aabbccddeeffgghh';
$output = substr($input, 0, 5) . substr($input, -5);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$extract = substr($input,0,5) . substr($input,-5);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use substr - http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php

Answer (score 1):

```
$hash = "aabbccddeeffgghh";
$tenChars = substr( $hash, 0, 5) . substr( $hash, -5 ); // "aabbcfgghh"
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to use [the substr function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php):

```
$md5hash = '098f6bcd4621d373cade4e832627b4f6';
$front_and_back = substr($md5hash,0,5) . substr($md5hash,-5);
```

Answer (score 0):

$string = "aabbccddeeffgghh";

$string1 = substr($string,0,5);

$string2 = substr($string,-5);

$string = $string1 . $string2 ;

Comment: You have not set input string in `substr` functions.

Comment: lol sorry, it just seemed such a trivial thing I didn't really looked at it twice :-p