# Display first and last five character from string in PHP

Tags: php

I want to display first and last 5 character from following string.

```
APA91bGjUqf8O8yoajdN9BNf2Hs1iVm3VL37X7rn1_XiU1bcKOWVyaIYYusL8f5BCgzSw1HhaPbgntuYHFCR0VWrqGb59nDHMVfgJ-zK0SA0SWw0dvdMEB8AwI-Ltn56aBb0L-0tP_pkqZIbPltb71-u6inawaPfQw
```

I want following output:

> APA91...aPfQw

How to solve?

Comment: I want to display output as i mention display in <table></tr><td></td></tr></table>

Comment: Use `substr` to get it done.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to extract first 5 and last 5 characters from a string using php?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7075941/how-to-extract-first-5-and-last-5-characters-from-a-string-using-php)

Comment: Thanks to all for quick reply...

Answer (score 10):

You can use the following:

```
if(strlen($input) > 10) {
  echo substr($input, 0, 5) . '...' . substr($input, -5);
} else {
  echo $input;
}
```

This will check the length of the `$input` first. In case less than 10 characters, that is meaningless to add `...` in the string.

Comment: I've always thought that when you truncate a string, it should print the original string when it's length is less than, or equal to the maximum length of the truncated string. `if (strlen($input) > 10 + strlen('...'))`.

Answer (score 3):

Use use this code. But you can do with `preg_match` too

```
$input  = 'your_string';
$output = substr($input, 0, 5) . substr($input, -5);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
echo substr($str,0,5).'...'.substr($str,-5)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$input  = 'APA91bGjUqf8O8yoajdN9BNf2Hs1iVm3VL37X7rn1_XiU1bcKOWVyaIYYusL8f5BCgzSw1HhaPbgntuYHFCR0VWrqGb59nDHMVfgJ-zK0SA0SWw0dvdMEB8AwI-Ltn56aBb0L-0tP_pkqZIbPltb71-u6inawaPfQw';
$output = substr($input, 0, 5) ."...". substr($input, -5);
```

This is what you need :)

Wayne

Answer (score 0):

```
echo substr('APA91bGjUqf8O8yoajdN9BNf2Hs1iVm3VL37X7rn1_XiU1bcKOWVyaIYYusL8f5BCgzSw1HhaPbgntuYHFCR0VWrqGb59nDHMVfgJ-zK0SA0SWw0dvdMEB8AwI-Ltn56aBb0L-0tP_pkqZIbPltb71-u6inawaPfQw', 0, 5) . '...' .substr('APA91bGjUqf8O8yoajdN9BNf2Hs1iVm3VL37X7rn1_XiU1bcKOWVyaIYYusL8f5BCgzSw1HhaPbgntuYHFCR0VWrqGb59nDHMVfgJ-zK0SA0SWw0dvdMEB8AwI-Ltn56aBb0L-0tP_pkqZIbPltb71-u6inawaPfQw', -5, 5);
```